# admob ads stop showing when android package name is changed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

Ive recently taken a step into basic java coding and now have an issue.

I bought some code which seems fine and builds the final app ok, well ish.

Basicly ive narrow the issue down of ads not been shown to when i change the android package name this then stops any ads showing.

Any help would be great im using eclipse and it doesnt throw any releivent errors.

Thanks rory